# SELECT where with multiple conditions in ONE query

Tags: mysql, join, select, union, where-clause

There are **two** things I want to achieve.

This is my database table called "table".

```
id | friend
---|--------
1  | null
2  | 1
3  | 0
4  | 3
5  | 3
6  | null
```

There are two SELECT queries I want to do.

```
$id = 3;
SELECT * FROM table WHERE id = $id; // Not sql injection safe, just an example
```

This should select row id = 3. If that row's `friend` column = 0, then:

```
SELECT rows WHERE friend = $id.
```

If that row's `friend` column is something other than 0, then just return that row, row 3. **But** since my table above shows that row id 3's `friend` column = 0, this should altogether return rows: 3, 4, 5.

---

**Also, another scenario a something a little different:**

```
$id = 5;
SELECT * FROM table WHERE id = $id;
```

If that row's `friend` column <> (does NOT equal) 0 AND IS NOT NULL, then use the `friend` number and:

```
SELECT * WHERE id = friend from previous table.
```

In this example, it will return rows 3, 4, 5 because ID = 5 and the `friend` ID of 5 is 3. So we search columns `id` AND `friend` for 3 and we select it.

I want to combine all of those together into one MySQL SELECT query. How can I do that?

Any help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

In the first scenario, I don't understand exactly why a zero value for `friend` returns 3, 4, and 5.  Why not 2?  I'm assuming that if the `friend` value is zero, then add the rows which have you as a friend.

So, before this first example, I cannot stand a table named "`table`", so I will use `friends` as the name of the table.

```
SELECT FF.id
FROM friends FF
  INNER JOIN friends FID on FF.friend = FID.id
WHERE FID.friend = 0 AND FID = $id
UNION
SELECT F2.id FROM friends F2 WHERE F2.id = $id AND F2.friend IS NOT NULL
```

The inner join, takes the id of friends (`FID.id`) and joins on the the friends table again to get all the records with that as a friend (`FF.friend`) value.

Then `UNION` will include the original id.  Both sides of the `UNION` will return no results if the friend field is NULL.

Similarly for the second scenario, use the given value, (`$id` = 5), find that record's `friend` value, and query for all records with that as a friend, then union its record.

```
SELECT FF.id
FROM friends FF
WHERE FF.friend = (SELECT FIN.friend FROM friends FIN where FIN.id = $id)
UNION
SELECT FIN.friend FROM friends FIN where FIN.id = $id
```

Comment: Is it possible to combine those two together?

Comment: I doubt it.  The reason I doubt it is that you are asking for results which relate to the given id in one way, and then also wanting to include a record which is not related that way.  I think UNION is the only way to get it into one query of the server.